# How to solve "permission denied" for a text file in Raspbian?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, file-permissions, raspbian

I have coded a Telegram script in python, using TelegramBotAPI.

It runs perfectly even in windows or in Ubuntu. But there is an issue in Raspbian.

One of the commands call an FTP file and try to write a text file, just with the simple following code.

```py
def bajarftp (remote_file):
    ftp = FTP("example.com")  
    ftp.login(user='xxx', passwd=".........")   
    localfile = open("archivo.txt","wb")
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ archivoremoto,localfile.write)
    ftp.quit()
    return
```

This is a function called from the TelegramBot.

This works on windows or in Ubuntu but in Raspbian the following error occurs

```
error "permission denied for archivo.txt".
```

I have written agaín the permission but the error still appears

Edit:

Pi:

```
$ id; pwd; ls -ld
uid=1000(pi) gid=1000(pi) grupos=1000(pi),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),29(audio),44(video),46(plugdev),60(games),100(users),101(input),108(netdev),997(gpio),998(i2c),999(spi)
/home/pi/bot2
drwxrwxrwx 3 pi pi 4096 ago 3 12:34 .
```

Ubuntu:

```
$ id; pwd; ls -ld
uid=1000(jmanuelab) gid=1000(jmanuelab) grupos=1000(jmanuelab),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),118(lpadmin),129(sambashare)
/home/jmanuelab/bot_2
drwxr-xr-x 3 jmanuelab jmanuelab 4096 jul 31 20:17 .
```

Comment: Does the user that the script is running as have write access to the current directory? Maybe put in a call to `os.chdir()` to change to a directory you can write to before calling the above code.

Comment: I call the script : python3 /home/user/pi/folder/script.py

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: But is works perfectly in ubuntu with the same file permissions The scripts do not need to change the directory

Comment: Does the user who is running the script have write access to the current directory on all three platforms? The script needn't change the directory if it is run from somewhere that the user has write access. What directory are you running the script from and as what user and what is the ownership/perms of that directory?

Comment: i.e. try: `id; pwd; ls -ld` on Ubuntu and Raspbian and add the results to your answer. Also include the full stacktrace you get.

Comment: id; pwd; ls -ld
uid=1000(pi) gid=1000(pi) grupos=1000(pi),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),29(audio),44(video),46(plugdev),60(games),100(users),101(input),108(netdev),997(gpio),998(i2c),999(spi)
/home/pi/bot2
drwxrwxrwx 3 pi pi 4096 ago  3 12:34 .

Comment: Ubuntu  uid=1000(jmanuelab) gid=1000(jmanuelab) grupos=1000(jmanuelab),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),118(lpadmin),129(sambashare)
/home/jmanuelab/bot_2
drwxr-xr-x 3 jmanuelab jmanuelab 4096 jul 31 20:17 .

Comment: Please run `ls -l archivo.txt` on both machines and include the results in the question. Please also add the full stack trace from the error to the question. Then perhaps someone more familiar with Raspberry Pi can help. The permissions look OK, so it might be that there is an existing archivo.txt on the Pi that is e.g. owned by root, or maybe the Pi is doing something weird with overlay filesystems.

Comment: ubuntu ls -l:    -rw-rw-r-- 1 jmanuelab jmanuelab 17408 jul 31 20:36 archivo.txt

Comment: raspbian ls-l;  -rw-rw-r-- 1 pi pi 9559 ago  4 18:41 archivo.txt

Comment: just the same permissions

Comment: It is completely crazy. I just copied the full directory from Raspibian to Ubuntu. When I run the python script in the Visual Studio Code console everything works fine but if I run in the Ubuntu Terminal....it cashes. "permision denied".....

Comment: Nomenclature: it doersn't 'crash', that's something totally different. It just refuses to do what you ask it to. You, and people here, are trying to find out why.

Comment: We need the exact output that it gives, not some paraphrase like "error appears", or "crashes".

Comment: Also, people were asking about permissions of a directory because you need to have execute access to *enter* a directory and, on top of that, you need *write* access to a directory to be able to add a file (archivo.text) to that directory. In addition to all that, you need to have user or group ownership of the directory to be able to even enter it.

Comment: Also it doesn't help much to keep referring in the comments to a system where things work. If becomes confusing to read after a certain point.

Comment: Which leads me to this question: where did the `archivo.txt` that exists on the Pi come from?  Apparently your script succeeded at least once....?

Comment: I'm not familiar with TelegramBotAPI, but maybe you should call 'open' with `rb+` or `wb+`?

Comment: No paraphrases: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jmanuelab/bot2/bot2.py", line 155, in <module>
    bot.polling()
  File "/home/jmanuelab/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 389, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
  File "/home/jmanuelab/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 413, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
...

Comment: ...  File "/home/jmanuelab/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 108, in raise_exceptions
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/jmanuelab/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telebot/util.py",

Comment: ...line 59, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jmanuelab/bot2/bot2.py", line 62, in mensaje_boya
    bajarftp("ftpfile.txt")
  File "/home/jmanuelab/bot2/st_library/zuni.py", line 41, in bajarftp
    localfile = open("archivo.txt","wb")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'archivo.txt'"

Comment: Please add the error details it to the question. Not comments.